# convergence, but not almost uniform convergence.

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

Can anyone help me with finding an example of function convergence, which is not an almost uniform convergence?

Comment: $f_n=\chi{[n,n+1]}$

Answer (score 3):

The "sliding hump" example $f_n=\chi_{[n,n+1]}$, given by derivative in a comment, is probably the simplest and most natural example of such convergence.